# Getting index of column of minimum value in a data.frame row

Tags: r

```
DF = structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 5L), b = c(2L, 3L, 3L), c = c(3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

a b c 
1 2 3 
2 3 1 
5 3 2
```

How do I create additional columns, each including the names or indices of the columns of the row minimum, middle and maximum as follows?

```
a b c min middle max
1 2 3   a      b   c
2 3 1   c      a   b
5 3 2   c      b   a
```

Comment: I'm removing the data.table tag, since this it refers to an R class not used here.

Comment: I suggest re-adding the data.table tag, since this it refers to an R class used here - in one answer; also, DF is.data.table as mentioned in the question title (and as in my actual code).

Comment: Tags pertain to the question, not the answers. For what it's worth, no, your code is not for a data.table; and it is not mentioned in the text of the question either. Try reading in `DF` with your code above and then running `class(DF)`. If you want to modify your question to be specific to data table (maybe by adding lines for `library(data.table)` and `setDT(DF)` and some edits to your wording), you can do that and I think the tag would fit better. You could also comment on josilber's answer to let him know you've made this change, in case he wants to update his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to loop through the rows with `apply`, returning the column names in the indicated order:

```
cbind(DF, t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) setNames(names(DF)[order(x)],
                                              c("min", "middle", "max")))))
#   a b c min middle max
# 1 1 2 3   a      b   c
# 2 2 3 1   c      a   b
# 3 5 3 2   c      b   a
```

This solution assumes you have exactly three columns (so the middle is the second largest). If that is not the case, you could generalize to any number of columns with the following modification:

```
cbind(DF, t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) {
  ord <- order(x)
  setNames(names(DF)[c(ord[1], ord[(length(x)+1)/2], tail(ord, 1))],
           c("min", "middle", "max"))
})))
#   a b c min middle max
# 1 1 2 3   a      b   c
# 2 2 3 1   c      a   b
# 3 5 3 2   c      b   a
```

Answer (score 3):

As the OP mentioned about `data.table`, here is one way with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DF)`), grouped by the sequence of rows, we `unlist` the dataset, `order` the values, use it as index to order column names, create three columns by assigning (after converting to `list`).

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(DF)[, c('min', 'middle', 'max') :=
    as.list(names(DF)[order(unlist(.SD))]) ,1:nrow(DF)][]
 #   a b c min middle max
 #1: 1 2 3   a      b   c
 #2: 2 3 1   c      a   b
 #3: 5 3 2   c      b   a
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag: `oneliner` ;)